# Prove that $x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_n>y_1y_2y_3\cdots y_m$ with some given conditions

Tags: inequality

$x_1, x_2, x_3,.\cdots ,x_n$ and $y_1, y_2, y_3,\ldots,y_m$ are two series of positive integers, such that $m\not=n$.

Given that  $1<x_1< x_2<x_3<\cdots<x_n<y_1< y_2< y_3<\cdots<y_m$ and  $x_1+ x_2+ x_3+\cdots+x_n > y_1+ y_2+ y_3+\cdots+y_m$, prove that  $x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_n>y_1y_2y_3\cdots y_m$.

I have tried to prove it for conservatives. I have no idea how to deal with this type of inequality properly.

Comment: Is there a reason you think it is true? What do you mean "conservatives?"

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: did you see this problem from a math journal?

Comment: Do you have $m<n$ ? Otherwise there is no solution. 

If $1<x_1<x_2<y_1<y_2<y_3$, then 
$(x_1+x_2)<(y_1+y_1)<(y_1+y_2+y_3)$

Comment: I think it's implied that $m<n$ since $x_1+\cdots+ x_n>y_1+\cdots +y_m$.

Comment: @Orca $m<n$ is guaranteed by the additive condition (along with the strictly increasing condition).

Comment: I think so: $nx_n\ge x_1+\cdots+x_n>y_1+\cdots+y_m\ge my_1$, and $x_n<y_1$.

Comment: I think this is  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality

Comment: @user21820 I don't know even how to solve this with the help of induction.

Comment: Not just that $m<n$, $m<\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_1}{x_n}$. 

In fact $m$ is even more severely restricted. 

Does this help ?

Comment: Sorry the solution I thought I had in my head vanished with a puff.